# matlab R2015a in Linux: Can't copy paste with conventional way

Tags: matlab, copy, paste

It seems that in linux version 'matlab R2015a' copy paste can not be done with 'Ctrl+c' and 'Ctrl+v'.
So how can I solve this? Is there any way to reconfigure matlab' to do this by, 'Ctrl+c' and 'Ctrl+v'.

Comment: Yu probably have set the keyboard shortcuts to emacs mode rather than Windows mode - see [Choose a Set of Keyboard Shortcuts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/keyboard-shortcuts.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com&nocookie=true) in the Matlab documentation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MATLAB has a preferences setting for keyboard shortcuts: it defaults to Emacs-compatible settings on Unix/Linux platforms, but you can change it to Windows-compatible settings <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> using the preferences menu:

[image: MATLAB - Keyboard Shortcuts Preferences]